# Ionic controller not called after $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, dom-events

I have a controller the get data from my back-end application when opening the state for the first time from the first controller it loads the data, but when it tries to open it again it does not load the new data

Here is how:

```
if (selectedServiceID == "000")
{
  $state.go('balanceInquery'); 
};
```

Here is the called `balanceInquery` state controller:

```
.controller('BalanceInqueryController', function($scope, getAccountBalanceService, $state, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup) {
  getAccountBalanceService.get(username, pass, customerID, serviceAccID, langID)
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.custBalance = data;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Error!',
        template: 'Sorry something went wrong'
      });
    });
})
```

Comment: I found that ionic framework views are cached to improve performance 
 In the latest ionic release (v1.0.0-beta.14) they introduced view caching. See IonView docs for more infos on that.

You could deactivate caching in for your route like this

http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionNavView/

Comment: Thanks, this saved me loads of time.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me loads.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem. The first time was shown only after reload. The reason is view caching. Disable it with ***cache: false***, like in my specific case:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl as vm',
    templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html'
  })
  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html',
    cache: false
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

This is due to view caching, which can be disabled in a variety of ways. See http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionNavView/ for more details.