# controller is not called as expected in $stateprovider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

### I have used $stateProvider in my angular application for routing. Prob I'm facing here is, on logout I could navigate to login page,but the login controller is not getting reloaded as expected. Please find below the $stateProvider configured in my app

in controller.js

$location.url('/login');

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'loginController'
  })
  .state('charts', {
      url: '/charts',
      templateUrl: 'templates/chart-screen.html',
      controller: 'ChartController'
  })
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

Comment: try to use $state.go('login'). inject the `$state` in your controller

Comment: Thanks for your response sachila, I also tried $state.go().but controller is not getting reloaded.

Comment: can you post the full code

Comment: Try `$state.go('login', {reload: true})`

Comment: I just created a basic ionic project with login and landing page. on clicking on logout button I can successfully navigate to login page based on url from landing page as expected, but login controller is not getting reloaded due to which i'm forced to use  "$window.location.reload();". and as I use window.location .reload, entire page reloads which causes flicker in the view?

Comment: tried "$state.go('login', {reload: true})" , but controller is not reloaded

Answer (score 0):

Controller is not reloaded because of caching, please refer below link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/31725101/6071335